# Setting up Local WebServer Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, apache, server

> **luvkapur.conf**

```
<Directory "/Users/luvkapur/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

> The following lines have been commented out from **httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

> The following line has been commented out from **httpd-userdir.conf**

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

> The error message displayed is : **404 Not Found**

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend using Homebrew to install Apache + PHP, rather than mess with the one that ships with OS X.

Comment: You tried looking at this guide on Apache in El Capitan: http://digitalshore.io/local-web-development-environment-apache-osx-10-11-el-capitan/?